# Python27 - Windows error or my python coding? strange message from function determine median

Tags: function, mean, mode, median

```
# testing entry of multiple numbers into a list. 
from collections import Counter
s = raw_input("Please enter your numbers: ")
numbers = map(int, s.split())
print 'this is what you entered'
print "how many entries? ", len(numbers)
mean = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
print 'and the Mean is', mean
mode = Counter(numbers)
print 'and the Mode is', mode.most_common(1)
def median(numbers):            
    numbers.sort()
    if len(numbers)%2 == 1:
        return numbers[len(numbers)/2]      
    else:      
        return (numbers[len(numbers)/2]+numbers[len(numbers)/2 -1])/2.0
print 'and the Median is', median
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 'strange output' you mention is the last line of output when you run your code:

```
and the Median is <function median at 0x0256D9B0>
```

(You may get a slightly different number.)

The reason is fairly simple.  You're not calling the `median` function, you're just printing it.

I think you want to replace the last line of your program with

```
print 'and the Median is', median(numbers)
```

Windows error or your Python coding?  Your Python coding, without a shadow of a doubt.